# react redux: Call a function if a socket event was called

Tags: reactjs, redux, socket.io, react-redux

I use React with Redux. I wait for a socket event 'connect' inside a component no. 1. When the socket is connected then I want to call some function inside a component no. 2. How to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I was going to use some custom event emitter and next add an event listener to the component no. 2. @Héctor

Answer (score 1):

If you are using socket.io you should be able to do this:

```
socket.on('connect', () => {
  yourFunction()
});
```

You could place that inside the componentWillMount() lifecycle hook of your component and then just call the function of your component with the regular this.yourFunction().

You can read more about the available client events here: [Socket.IO Client API](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/)

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out.